# POST request to Spotify API saying no token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify

I am getting this error message when I am trying a POST request:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
}
```

The thing is I am passing in an access token by making a headers variable and assigning it to the headers for the post request like this:

```
const headers = {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
```

```
return fetch(`https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/${userId}/playlists`, {
                'headers': headers,
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({'name': name})
```

This fetch request is the one giving me the error I stated above. How can I fix this?

[Headers object picture right before the fetch request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4WL9.jpg)

Here is the link to the GitHub: https://github.com/aoljaca/jamming

This code is in the src/utils/Spotify document

Thanks!

Comment: The docs say it must be `Authorization: Basic *<base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>*` as the format. 

Check out the section header parameter. 

https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/

I believe it uses `Basic` as the auth header.

Comment: yes I am using implcit grant flow https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow however which I'm pretty sure does not need a client secret

Answer (score 0):

I tried running your code but it threw a different error before it it was able to reach that part of your program.

One possible debugging strategy is making sure the `headers` variable is still defined and includes the access key before returning the fetch request. Just print it to console before running that particular fetch. If it goes out of scope at some point in your promise chain then it could be `null`.

I'd also suggest using `headers: headers` instead of `'headers': headers`.

Comment: That is exactly what I just did and headers did return a token. Ill add a picture to my original post. Also why does the code crash for you but works for me? Is it because I did not fully deploy the react app? Thanks

Comment: Open the developer console and check the actual network request that is being made. You should be able to see the headers used.

Comment: Just did but its not really helping me solve the problem so far